# Difference between "um" and "umher"

Tags: difference

What is the difference between *umher* and *um*?

> 1. Ich gehe ***um*** den Park.
> 2. Ich gehe ***im Park*** umher.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are different words: *gehen* (to go, to walk) and umhergehen (to perambulate). You are either walking around the park, or walking around in the park.

Comment: Perambulate? Why not simply *to stroll*? I'm strolling in/through the park.

Comment: Slightly different register, I think. But I'm really fine with either.

Answer (score 10):

> Ich gehe **um** den Park.

is a short form for

> Ich gehe **um** den Park **herum**".

So you are searching the difference between "ich gehe herum" (Verb: "herumgehen") and "ich gehe umher" (Verb: "umhergehen").

The Duden says both mean the same

[Herumgehen - Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/herumgehen)

[Umhergehen - Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/umhergehen)

but there is some difference between them.

When you use "herumgehen" you have to differ if you walk around a certain point (**um den Park herum**). In this case, "herumgehen" means to walk around something. If not, it means the same as "umhergehen": to walk aimlessly around (**Im Park herum**).

So, your sentences mean the following:

1. Ich gehe **um** den Park : I'm walking around (outside of) the Park.
2. Ich gehe **im Park** umher: I'm (aimlessly) walking inside of the Park.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to say "ich gehe im Park herum"? meaning "I'm (aimlessly) walking inside of the Park."?

So "ich gehe im Park herum" = ich gehe im Park umher?"

Comment: Hi Ozzy Jones! Welcome to German SE! Your post does not seem to be an answer to the question, but rather a question on its own. If it is your intention to ask a question, please open a new thread for this and delete this post here. One principle of this website is to have only one question per thread. The aim of this is to make it easier for future readers of the thread to find the information they are looking for. Please also take the tour as an introduction to this site: https://german.stackexchange.com/tour